# Is there any dependency between SNR and Link Speed for WiFi AP?

Tags: wifi, snr

Today we use RSSI as indicator of AP quality. However even if you have `rssi=-45dm` it's not enough to say that AP WiFi guarantees you good BW. Because if many clients connected to the same AP and some of them have the same channel the `RSSI` still will be good but actually we get low BW (throughput).

For that reason I try to fetch SNR or Noise from AP. The problem is - for mobiles like Android and iOS we can't get nor SNR neither Noise. I have only `RSSI` and AP `Link speed`.

For that reason I try to find any correlation between SNR and Link Speed.

Any suggestions, documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for radio receivers there is the following "rule of thumb" formula that describes the minimum received antenna power needed to operate at a low bit error rate: -

Receive power (dBm) = -154 dBm + 10log\$_{10}\$(data rate)

So if you have a 1Mbps data stream, you need to ensure the received signal is: -

-154 dBm + 60 dBm = -94 dBm.

I call it a rule of thumb because there is so much variability in radio but the actual formula is derived mathematically and I can recommend the document I use: -

"Essentials of radio wave propagation" by Christopher Haslett. I got mine by googling but it is getting difficult to find this way (without paying money of course)

OK try [here](https://nvhrbiblio.nl/biblio/boek/Haslett%20-%20Essentials%20of%20radio%20wave%20propagation.pdf) and look on page 14: -

[image]

Comment: It's very interesting, I'm going to read it. Sounds like it's what I'm looking for.